# iOS - backgroundTimeRemaining value not showing what expected

Tags: ios, time, background, multitasking

I'm trying to check the value of `backgroundTimeRemaining`, but I get a very large number. The value of the property is supposed to be the corresponding to 10 min aprox, and I`ve read in Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication) that such value is large when the app is in the foreground. However, I get a large value even when in background:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
      [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
      bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
   }];

   // Background task
   NSTimeInterval timeRemaining = [UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining;
   NSLog(@"Background time remaining: %f seconds (%d mins)", timeRemaining, (int)(timeRemaining / 60));

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
      NSTimeInterval timeRemaining = [UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining;
      NSLog(@"Background time remaining: %f seconds (%d mins)", timeRemaining, (int)(timeRemaining / 60));

      // Perform task

      // Finished
      if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
         [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
         bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
      }
  });

  // Start location manager
  if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {          
     [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
  }
}
```

What could am I missing?

Comment: I think the background task won't be started until the `applicationDidEnterBackground` event has been handled completely.

Comment: Then... how could I request the `backgroundTimeRemaining` value?

Comment: try within a dispatch_async block on the main thread

Comment: your code is working in the iOS simulator, I got 10 minutes background time.

Comment: really? I get weird values both in simulator and device...

Comment: I'm also getting weird values in both simulator and device (like 2147483648 mins). Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

The watchdog timer is disabled when running from Xcode.

I mostly get sensible values (ie. 600) when running unconnected, but I still get the occasional weird value.

Comment: That's weird since you can't then test against failures. I wish this wasn't the case.