# Why is UIApplication's backgroundTimeRemaining value DBL_MAX when application state is background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I am looking at a log message generated by the snippet of code below.  Flog is a #define for a call to an internal logging class.

The code is from a source file within a Pod included in my project.  I don't know if that's significant or not.

I'm baffled by the message, since the application state is compared to UIApplicationStateBackground before the log statement is executed.

*What am I missing here?*

[04/05/16 18:31:21] Background time remaining (in didVisit method): 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.00 seconds...

```
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
        backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
            FLog(@"Background time remaining (in didVisit method): %.2f seconds...", [UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);
        }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this.I have got a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's why https://stackoverflow.com/a/18256062/3900270

It won't work while Xcode's debugger is attached